# Do DOM Manipulation (append a script tag) without adding to current DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, dom

I'm trying to prepend a script into the HEAD of the page DOM's HTML and return it as a string, but without actually modifying the current page. I just want the string output and not actually affect the current page.

I have the following code which works perfectly in Firefox/Chrome but in IE9 it's causing an ACTUAL DOM manipulation:

```
var htmlstr = $("head").html()

var div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = htmlstr;

var ca = document.createElement("script");
ca.type = "text/javascript";
ca.src = "somefile.js";

div.insertBefore(ca, div.firstChild || null);
```

I can see in the IE console that the line "ca.src = " is triggering an actual download of the file and insertion into the page DOM rather than just simulating it with the temporary div I created. Is there any better way to accomplish this or some fix that can make IE fall in line? I understand that this may be a strange request, but there's no server-side workaround that's doable for us.

I should add that we don't want any JS in the html string to actually execute.

Comment: I can see why IE would download the script, but are you sure it really puts it into the document (and if so, where does it put it)? Does it actually *run* the script? This seems unlikely to me, but I don't have IE on this machine to check.

Comment: @DaggNabbit I'm not sure if it's inserted into the document, but I know the script is being run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could keep an iframe on the page available for this and then modify the iframe and retrieve the contents from the iframe.

You could also try using an iframe to achieve the same results.

```
i = $("iframe");
s = $("script").attr("src","somefile.js");
z = i.contents().createElement("script");
z.type = "text/javascript";
z.src = "somefile.js";
i.contents().insertBefore(ca,i.contents().firstChild||null);
```

i.contents() should have the result with the  tag.

Let me know if this helps at all.

Comment: Thanks for the response Brent, appreciate it. The problem with this approach is that it will executive any javascript in the HTML string, which is undesirable.

Comment: Also turns out jQuery doesn't allow you to add a script tag, because of security reasons apparently. It instead eval's the script tag.